# Access video frame buffer in callback in HAL 1.0

Tags: android, android-camera, hal

I am working on the camera HAL 1.0 for Android. I have read in the documentation that the video frames are returned in the camera_data_timestamp_callback with a CAMERA_MSG_VIDEO_FRAME message.

When I check the data in the camera_memory_t* parameter, there are only 8 bytes of data in it. My questions are, what are these 8 bytes and how can I use this data to access the actual buffer with the video frame data?

Comment: which device are you exploring?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I would guess it's a gralloc reference, probably the same as what's defined here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/lollipop-release/media/libstagefright/SurfaceMediaSource.cpp#251

Comment: @AlexCohn It's a custom device from a small company. It's based on Snapdragon 410.

Comment: @fadden That looks exactly like the answer I wanted. I will check it out if it works. Thanks.

Comment: @fadden It seems like you were half right. The data contains the type kMetadataBufferTypeCameraSource and a native_handle_t. It seems this memory is not allocated with gralloc.

Comment: $fadden The handle seems to be a handle to a ION-allocated buffer (i.e. not a gralloc buffer). Do you know a way to map the handle (or the file descriptor) to a memory address?

Comment: Have you seen https://code.google.com/p/android-source-browsing/source/browse/QualcommCameraHardware.cpp?repo=platform--hardware--qcom--camera ?